# How to pass multiple arguments in flutter fluro

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter fluro for routing. I was able to pass only one arguments and was able to access it in the page. How can I send multiple items?

Here is how I am using

```
router.define('/about/:id', handler: new Handler(handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
    return new AboutPage(params["id"][0]);
 }));
```

I am calling this like this

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/about/23");
```

Now I want to pass more than one variables like this

`Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/about/23/newdata");`

I tried to access this new data like this

```
router.define('/about/:id/:str', handler: new Handler(handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
    return new AboutPage(params["id"][0], params["id"][1]);
}));
```

It doesn't work. It gives me error like this

```
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/about/23/newdata", null) in the
```

flutter: _WidgetsAppState.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here an exemple to access all parameters :

```dart
router.define(
      '/testpage/:param1/:param2/:param3',
      handler: Handler(
        handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
          print('Navigate to TestPage');
          var param1 = params['param1'][0];
          var param1 = params['param2'][0];
          var param1 = params['param3'][0];
        },
      ),
    );
```

So for you :

```dart
router.define('/about/:id/:str', handler: new Handler(handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
    return new AboutPage(params['id'][0], params['str'][0]);
}));
```

Have a nice day !

Comment: How to pass url as a parameter in other class? I have passed the url in a same way but it doest works, {No registered route was found to handle 'PLAYER_DETAIL/Kevin Nguyen/https://images.abc.gg/images/user/723298/image-f6c907294263b348657dcefb956820c3.png'}